# What are necessary SQL table columns for uploaded files?

Tags: mysql, database

What are the necessary table columns to be used in order to store an uploaded file's information to the database?

Here is what I made so far using MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `files` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `file_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `file_extension` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `file_path` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `file_size` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` varchar(50),
  `date_accessed` varchar(50),
  `date_modified` varchar(50),
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `directory_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Is there something you wish I must add/remove columns?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what you need to know about the uploaded file.

But all your listed things can be read directly form the file using the [PHP Filesystem](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filesystem.php)-commands.

One thing that should be written in the database is the [MD5](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php) or [SH1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1-file.php) checksum of the file so the download can be verified as non corrupt.